# Control VBScript using VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript

To achieve multithreading, I'm writing using VBA to construct VBScript code (`VBStr`) and write to file on-the-fly, before launching these helper scripts asynchonously:

```
Dim VBFile As Object
Dim VBPath As String
VBPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & GUID() & ".vbs"
Set VBFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(VBPath)
VBFile.WriteLine VBStr
VBFile.Close

Dim Shell As Object
Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Shell.Run """" & VBPath & """"
```

However, how to control these scripts back in VBA? I can't seem to get a handle or reference to them. Say I want to terminate hung/stalled scripts after 60secs - how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .Exec instead of .Run. The returned [WshScriptExec Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) has methods/properties to monitor the status of and to terminate the process.